# Is it possible to add a mobile operator to Xcode iPhone simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

So I need to add a mobile operator to Xcode simulator. Currently it looks like this [image: no mobile operator at all]

And i want it to be like this[image: (the carrier thing)]

So my question is if there's a way to do it in the Xcode simulator and if so how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so that you can achieve exactly same that you posted in question but in iOS we have flexibility to change simulator status bar like battery level, time, WiFi state, cellular state.

this feature is called `simctl` you can Google more details about it.

to specifically change status bar use `simctl status_bar`

Answer (score 1):

The status icons you see depends on the model of the iPhone. According to [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT207354), phones that use Face ID do not display the carrier in the status bar, and phones that use Touch ID do.

> [image]
>
> iPhone models with Face ID
>
> [image]
>
> iPhone models with Touch ID

So just go to File -> Open Simulator, and select a different simulator that uses Touch ID, such as iPhone SE.

Also,

> If you can't see an icon, [check Control Centre](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202769) by swiping down from the top right-hand corner.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think u can add mobile cause of similator doesn't have SIM card. operator.Similator can work as a real device as coding, but it does not contain all the features of the real device. Simulator is a program and other device.

If you want to do something for a feature that can only be on a real device try this with a real device like mobile operator operations

It's similar to taking a photo from the phone and uploading it to the app. The simulator does not have a camera feature, so if you try to open the camera in the simulator, the application will crash. You need to test this on a real device